# CSS relative path to image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a `DIV's` background with an image in "Images" folder using `CSS`.
What should be the relative path to my image in CSS. My site's directory structure  is as shown in this [image](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwNDl3elmQN_V3Vqb3ZCREdzZlE/view)

I tried:

```
background: url("/Images/img1.jpg");
```

But this didn't work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: That should work fine.

Comment: @Quentin Oh oops, makes sense! I read that too quickly. =P

Comment: thats good i think . `background-image: url(/images/img1.jpg);` it must work i dont know why isnt working

Comment: @felixsturm — The OP said the directory was called Images, not images.

Comment: So did you verify the image is accessible at the expected URL?

Comment: @imRen, it would be awesome for you to give a true example of your fie structure, in text form. The image you gave is clearly hand made, which means any inaccuracies will stop us from answering ( for example, it's probably not _actually_ called `Images folder`, right?  See how that stops us from really being able to answer?)

Comment: html tag "<img src="./Images/img1.jpg">" or "<img src="Images/img1.jpg">" works just fine but CSS code "background-image: url("/Images/img1.jpg");" is not working. Can it be accebility issue?

Comment: put your full code

Comment: @felixsturm — So plenty of web servers run on computers with case sensitive file systems. Changing to a lower case `i` would break it.

Comment: @imRen — No. I can think of *lots* of things that it *might* be, but you need to provide a proper [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin i didnt know that. thanks for this information! :)

Comment: update: html tag "<img src="./Images/img1.jpg">" or "<img src="Images/img1.jpg">" works just fine but CSS code "background-image: url("/Images/img1.jpg");" is not working. Can it be accebility issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, when setting path of images in a CSS file, you can :

**1 - use absolute path :**

```
http://yourdomain.ext/Images/img1.jpg
```

**2 - Use relative path :**

BUT in that case, the path should be relative to the CSS file position.

In your case:

```
../../../Images/img1.jpg
```

Comment: I am working offline. Actually, "../../../Images/img1.jpg" worked. Thanks.